# default in switch statement is not working

Tags: c++, visual-studio, switch-statement, default

Hello I have the following problem.
I didnt find it anywhere on stackoverflow.
I want to make a default case for my switch statement but when the default case happens nothing happens.
You can see my code here:

```
    int main() 
    {
        char riegel;
        std::cout << "Please choose a chocolate! (a-d)";
        std::cin >> riegel;
        if (riegel == 'a' || riegel == 'b' || riegel == 'c' || riegel == 'd' || riegel == 'A' || riegel 
    == 'B' || riegel == 'C' || riegel == 'D')
    {
        switch (riegel)
        {
            case 'a': std::cout << "You chose Snickers" << std::endl; break;
            case 'b': std::cout << "You chose Milky Way." << std::endl; break;
            case 'c': std::cout << "You chose MARS." << std::endl; break;
            case 'd': std::cout << "You chose Kinder-Riegel." << std::endl; break;
            case 'A': std::cout << "You chose Snickers." << std::endl; break;
            case 'B': std::cout << "You chose Milky Way." << std::endl; break;
            case 'C': std::cout << "You chose MARS." << std::endl; break;
            case 'D': std::cout << "You chose Kinder-Riegel" << std::endl; break;
            default: std::cout << "Chocolate not found." << std::endl; break;
        }
    }



}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `switch` statement is inside the `if` statement

```
if (riegel == 'a' || riegel == 'b' || riegel == 'c' || riegel == 'd' || riegel == 'A' || riegel 
== 'B' || riegel == 'C' || riegel == 'D')
```

So when `riegel` is not the value covered by the `case` labels, the `switch` statement will not be executed.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you never enter the switch-statement when you enter another character. Try removing the whole if-Statement, because it is useless to check the condition twice, once with the switch and once with the if.

Answer (score 1):

This Happens because , you are filtering out only the needed choices "a", "b", "c" , "d"  in the IF loop  `if (riegel == 'a' || riegel == 'b' || riegel == 'c' || riegel == 'd' || riegel == 'A' || riegel  == 'B' || riegel == 'C' || riegel == 'D')` before calling the switch statement.

So the `if` statement does not even allow the bad choices to enter the switch loop.

Remove the if statement ,and you will get the desired output for default case

```
#include<iostream>

int main()
{
    char riegel;
    std::cout << "Please choose a chocolate! (a-d)";
    std::cin >> riegel;

    switch (riegel)
    {
        case 'a':
        case 'A':
         std::cout << "You chose Snickers" << std::endl;
         break;
        case 'b':
        case 'B':
             std::cout << "You chose Milky Way." << std::endl;
             break;
        case 'c':
        case 'C'
         std::cout << "You chose MARS." << std::endl; 
         break;
        case 'd':
        case 'D':
         std::cout << "You chose Kinder-Riegel." << std::endl; 
         break;
         
        default: 
        std::cout << "Chocolate not found." << std::endl;
         break;
    }

}
```

Further, you can use the above syntax for using multiple conditions for a switch case

Comment: `if` is not a loop, it's just a statement.

Comment: @SebastianRedl, Sorry typo..Edited the Solution. Thanks for pointing it out